# Firestore ServerTimestamp Sometimes Return Null in Model - Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my app user can post in their wall like in Facebook and every time there is a new post it will be displayed in RecyclerView as soon as it save in my collection. Previously I am using the device system time to save a timestamp withoit any error. But since it is a wrong approach, now I am saving it in a document's field using `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` and it also works really fine, but there is a new problem. Since the scenario is whenever there is a new post that item  will immediately gets displayed in the RecyclerView with the aid of a`POJO` and `addSnapshotListener` but now the timestamp gets null in every **new added item or fresh item**, but when I restart the app  the timestamp is correct.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.bitwise.rotaractclubapp, PID: 23528
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Date com.google.firebase.i.d()' on a null object reference
                  at com.bitwise.rotaractclubapp.a.l$1$1.a(NewsfeedRecyclerAdapter.java:187)
                  at com.google.android.gms.g.w.run(Unknown Source)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5530)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:733)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:623)
                  at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:107)
```

This is my sample model

```
//Importation
import com.google.firebase.Timestamp;


public String uid, description;
public Timestamp time;
public boolean file;

//Needed for Firebase
public NewsfeedsModel(){}

public NewsfeedsModel(String uid, String description, Timestamp time, boolean file) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.description = description;
    this.time = time;
    this.file = file;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public Timestamp getTime() {
    return time;
}

public boolean isFile() {
    return file;
}
```

This is how I convert it to java.util.Date inside onBindViewHolder and error happens here if new item is added.

```
 Date date = postList.get(rightPosition).getTime().toDate();
```

I also add this lines before anything else in my Application in hoping that it will fix the problem.

```
FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
            .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
            .build();

    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().setFirestoreSettings(settings);
```

Comment: Please add the code and indicate the at which your are getting this error and please also add a screenshot of your database.

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo thanks for your Algolia with Firestore, by the way I update my question my database is pretty simple there is a Users collection where document id is equal to user's Id then fields inside that document such as time_stamp where the data type is timestamp

Comment: You're welcome. Please add that screenshot to see the database and the timestam property more clearly.